# SQL - Select recipes that share similar number ingredients from MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, algorithm

I have three tables. recipes, ingredients and recipeingredients. recipeingredients contains ri_recipeid and ri_ingredientid and each record is an ingredient in a recipe.

I want to randomly select a set of recipes that all contain, lets say, at least 3 of the same ingredients. How would I go about doing this?

I hope I'm in the right place, thanks!

edit: I'm not even sure if this is possible to do in SQL, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: Define "similar ingredients". Also show what you've tried so far

Comment: You would write a sql query that selects the recipes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following links will help you to meet your requirements.

[Recipe Database, search by ingredient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427389/recipe-database-search-by-ingredient)

[SQL query - Find the names of those ingredients of which we used a total of 4 or more teaspoons across all recipes in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40265191/sql-query-find-the-names-of-those-ingredients-of-which-we-used-a-total-of-4-or)

[Checking that a recipe contains an ingredient - MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569065/checking-that-a-recipe-contains-an-ingredient-mysql)

[MySQL Database for Cookbook, Recipes, Ingredients](https://gist.github.com/greghelton/1546514)